# Dynamic multilevel each() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, recursion, each

I am having trouble creating  a muti-level each() using jQuery. This is my code but this is limited to 3 levels. I would like to make it to work with infinite levels.

Here is a JsFiddle demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/cWJH5/1/

### HTML

```
<nav id="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">DEMO</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### JS

```
Startlevel = 0;  
$('#menu > ul').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('item-' + i + ' level-' + Startlevel );
    menuLevel++;
    $(this).find('> li > ul').each(function (i) {
        $(this).addClass('item-' + i + ' level-' + Startlevel );
        menuLevel++;
        $(this).find('> li > ul').each(function (i) {
            $(this).addClass('item-' + i + ' level-' + Startlevel );
            menuLevel++;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need recursive function like below. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x5WDc/

```
var level = 0;

var assign_classes = function (list) {
  list.each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('item-' + i + ' level-' + level);
    level++;
    assign_classes($(this).find('> li > ul'));
    level--;
  });
};

assign_classes($('#menu > ul'));
```

Comment: is it possible in the same function to add the item + i to all "li"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just this:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cWJH5/3/)

```
$('#menu ul').each(function () {
    var Startlevel = $(this).parents('#menu ul').length;
    $(this).addClass('item-' + $('#menu ul.level-' + Startlevel).length + ' level-' + Startlevel);

});
```